# Why is the output reversed along with the first character missing?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *a;   
    char *temp ='55515';
    a = &temp;  
    printf("%s ", a);
}
```

The expected output is 55515 but the actual output is 5155?

Comment: `'55515'` is too long for a character literal, `a = &temp` assigns a `char**` to a `char*`, `i` is unused, why do you expect any part of this to work?

Comment: didn't your compiler give you *any warnings at all*?

Comment: Use `temp = "555515"`, and `printf("%s", temp);`...

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the output is reveresed.

Comment: '555515' is different with "555515". AND printf("%s", *a); is different with printf("%s", a);  *a= value of temp but a=address of temp.

Comment: Haha. That's a good one.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *a;
    char *temp ="55515";
    a = temp;
    printf("%s ", a);
}

Comment: There is nothing to comment. OP must just start to learn C. At the moment he does not even know the basics of the basics. Any comment and help is pointless id someone does not understand what the string C

Answer (score 0):

`'55515'` is a multi-character constant that is converted to `int`. Your platform has 32-bit `int`s so the MSB byte is discarded, and the resulting `int` is `(int)0x35353135`. This is then converted to a pointer to `char` in an implementation-defined manner. Your platform is a little-endian platform, and the char conversion retains the `int` value. The *value* of the pointer object is now laid out in memory as

```
temp:   
| 0x35 | 0x31 | 0x35 | 0x35
```

or

```
| 0x35 | 0x31 | 0x35 | 0x35
```

It cannot be deducted whether or not you're using 64-bit or 32-bit platform.
Now you make *another* pointer to `char *` that points to the first byte of the *pointer object*, i.e. the byte `0x35`, then `printf` this as a string with `%s`.

Depending on your platform the `printf` call has only implementation-defined behaviour or also possibly undefined behaviour - it depends on whether your pointers are 32 or 64 bits wide - if 32, then you have undefined behaviour, if 64, you're just depending on implementation-defined behaviour. All in all, not something that a strictly-conforming program would rely on.

Comment: Above answer is correct, but note that  serious compiler will emit a warning, or TWO:

Comment: added code sample